# Google Cloud Messaging unregister device

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging, cloud

I have added the module GCM and it works with APPENGINE correcty. I've done the documentation says to register and receive messages from Endpoint.

Now I wan't to unregister a device and I don't know how do it....
Any idea ?

I have tested gcm.unregister() and regService.unregister(Idphone).execute() but it doesn't work

I've tried to do a new AsyncTask class GcmUnRegistrationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
    private static Registration regService = null;
    private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    private Context context;

```
private static final String SENDER_ID = "892982546498";

public GcmUnRegistrationAsyncTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    if (regService == null) {

        Registration.Builder builder = new Registration.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                .setRootUrl("https://myproject.appspot.com/_ah/api/");
        regService = builder.build();

    }

    String msg = "";
    try {
        if (gcm == null) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        }
        String regId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
        msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;

    MainActivity.token=regId;


 regService.unregister(regId).execute();
gcm.unregister();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        msg = "Error: " + ex.getMessage();
    }
    return msg;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
  //  Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Logger.getLogger("unREGISTRATION").log(Level.INFO, msg);
    Toast.makeText(context, MainActivity.token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

I would like to show all devices too......

Comment: The `gcm.register()` and `gcm.unregister()` methods are all deprecated. You need to use the `instanceId` api instead. For the sample demo is here: https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/master/samples/android/gcm-demo Also the code for the registration: https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/399e88c1ef5bb95395b6392f9061e45b2fb5d49a/samples/android/gcm-demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/logic/InstanceIdHelper.java

Comment: Thanks, deprecated? I added the module GCM in Android Studio two weeks ago. Maybe it's not update...